# Partition the dataset by months

Tags: r

I have a column in my dataset for the date and its format is day/month/year like this (25/10/2015) and I want to partition it by month to have the rows for each month separated so I want to assign each month to a different variable like ( jan<- "code i should write to save the first month rows" ) and so on.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `split` the dataset by converting the 'date' to `Date` class and extract the `month` part with `format`

```
split(df,  format(as.Date(df$date, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%m'))
```

Or the month can be extracted with `regex`

```
split(df, gsub("^[^/]+/|/[^/]+$", "", df$date))
```

Comment: but what if i want to assign each month to a different variable like ( jan<- "code i should write to save the first month rows" ) and so on

Comment: @BishoyFam, you *can* do that with `assign()`, but you **really shouldn't**, in the long run your life will be easier if you learn to work with the data as a list of months: once you've split, you can just refer to the January variables via `split_df[[1]]` ...